# Extract url based on specific keyword

Tags: regex

I am crawling data from certain websites and I am looking to extract data from specific urls. One such case let say url with `*devicehelp.optus.com.au/web/*` as as example. PFB my regex -

```
/[^]*devicehelp\.optus\.com\.au\/web\/[^.]*/
```

This regex doesn't give me perfect match what I am looking for. Could someone please let me know what am I missing here?

Test urls -

```
*devicehelp.optus.com.au/web/*
http://www.top.abc.something.optus.devicehelp.optus.com.au/web/web/web/
```

This regex works when I test it on http://regexr.com/ but doesn't on https://regex101.com/

Comment: "This regex doesn't give me perfect match what I am looking for." What does it do and how is that different from what you want? Or are you hoping we'll just guess?

Comment: In general, it helps if you describe what your input looks like (I guess a list of URLs?) and what output you'd like to get (maybe a subset of those URLs, or maybe some piece of information located in the URLs, etc.). If you give sample input and sample output, I'm sure someone will be able to help.

Comment: My bad, added a few test urls

Comment: What you think  your `[^.]*` means?

Comment: Try `.*device....web/.*`

Comment: Maybe you want `.*devicehelp\.optus\.com\.au\/web\/.*`? Hard to guess without knowing what output you expect. (E.g. `.*` would match the line you shared.)

Comment: Also, same result you get without these markers. Because you don't use any anchors. Just try `devicehelp\.optus\.com\.au\/web\/`

Comment: Yeh it works with global for multiple urls

Comment: "Yeh it works with global for multiple urls" I have no idea what that means. Is your problem solved?

Comment: @smarx- yes it's solved. I was testing with multiple urls and added //g

Comment: What is the target environment? Where will the regex be used? Do you really need the `.*` at all?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am working on HPE IDOL. Yeh, .* solved it.

Answer (score 1):

In most regex flavors, `[^]` is an invalid regex construct, while on the site you tested (regexr.com), this will be parsed as *any character* (since the regexr regex flavor is JavaScript).

To *match any character but a newline zero or more times*, you may use `.*`.

```
.*\bdevicehelp\.optus\.com\.au\/web\/.*
```

The `\b` is a word boundary, so as to match `devicehelp` as a whole word (if you do not intend to match it as a whole word, you may remove it). Dots should be escaped to match literal dots.